# Problemas con un .csv

Tags: r, csv

El .csv tiene la siguiente estructura en cada fila:

**524542352213412345215,Active Account,"€ 0,00",542334-12315-542151 00:00:00,No Restructuring In Place,1**

Quiero procesarlo con R para convertirlo en una tabla normal pero me encuentro con un problema: el formato de los €(que está entre comillas en la tercera columna) lo separa como dos campos al tener separador coma(totalmente comprensible). El problema es que tengo distintos valores en esa columna, si no sería tan sencillo como reemplazar en un editor de texto. Lo que busco es cambiar el separador de todos los campos a excepción del de los €s(o cambiar únicamente el separador de los €s).
He buscado las formas de hacerlo pero la verdad que no he encontrado nada.

Comment: Estando el campo de los € entre comillas, R debería abrirlo como un solo campo de formato character (si usas `read.csv`) ¿en que formato te lo abre?

Comment: Me parece que lo más fácil y seguro sería importarlo con las columnas separadas y luego limpiar y volver a unir en una sola columna dentro de R. Si pones un ejemplo reproducible seguro recibirás ayuda. Puedes usar la función `dput()` para obtener una salida en texto que es literal de un objeto en R. Usar  regex para retocar un .csv suele ser peligroso, no es recomendable.

Comment: Daniel, no se si tienes forma de actuar sobre la generación del archivo, por que lo cierto es que el problema es ahí, no es correcto generar un archivos con columnas separadas por coma y que esta además sea separador decimal. Ahora bien, `read.csv()`, como te comentaron, es bastante inteligente en el sentido que al detectar las comillas lee todo como una cadena, incluida la coma.  Has probado hacer algo así: `read.csv("archivo.csv", encoding = "UTF-8")`?